# mce-inject for PowerPC

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, powerpc

I am new to PowerPC architecture and trying to implement mce-inject command(like on x86).The requirement is to inject the machine check(Instruction Cache Parity Error) in running PowerPC linux kernel.

As per below link, I could see if MSR[ME] and L1CSR1[ICPE] are set, it would generate machine check interrupt.

http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/AN3532.pdf

I Would like to know is it enough to generate machine check interrupt and call the machine check handler(in case of PowerPC, I belief machine_check_e500mc is the handler) ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 6 weeks old and likely you have already solved it by yourself. However, because the solution might be useful for others and I had to solve the same thing for an e200 core, here is how I did it.

It's not the e500 core but the e200 should be close enough.

You'll find most of the details about the instruction cache [here](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/E500CORERM.pdf).

The following are the relevant registers of the instruction cache of the e200.

```
L1CSR1[ICECE] (e500: L1CSR1[ICEP])
L1CSR1[ICEA]  (e500: -)
L1CSR1[ICEI]  (e500: L1CSR1[ICPI])
```

1. It's important that the handler is uncached, because the core is not capable of handling dual faults in terms of machine check interrupts. The application note linked in the question states what else to take care of in the handler. The page with the handler should have a mapping on the MMU all the time, otherwise you'd have to deal with a page fault first. In Linux, you'll very likely not have to worry about that. It's just for your understanding. Since the handler already seems to exist as machine_check_e500mc, likely someone has already taken care of all this.
2. Whether the instruction cache is enabled for a page depends on the CACHE_INHIBITED bit on the MMU which you set or clear by means of the MAS2 register when you create the mapping. For your special case it is important that the page is not cached, that's why I recommend you make sure it isn't. I cannot say how you figure this out in the Linux kernel. Maybe they have it in their page attributes. If they don't, you'd have to go all the way down to the MMU itself. If you do not encounter any parity errors inside your handler, their page is already uncached. Then you do not need to worry about it. The following is an example for the case there is no operating system. I've included the VLE_NOT_SET flag because I think that gcc is not capable of generating VLE instructions anyway. It's not important for the task at hand.

   ```
   #define MAS2                     626
   #define VLE_NOT_SET              0x00u
   #define CACHE_INHIBITED_SET      0x01u

   e_ori r2,r2,((VLE_NOT_SET << 5) | (CACHE_INHIBITED << 3))
   mtspr MAS2, r2
   ```
3. The core expects the handler for machine check interrupts in the IVOR1 register. In fact, IVOR1 just holds the lower word (16 bits) of the address of the handler. The upper word (16 bits) of the address is in the IVPR register which holds the base address for all interrupt handlers. The name machine_check_e500mc suggests that it is it. If you want to go after it, you'd look for a code snippet like the following. Whatever is installed in IVOR1 is the handler.

   ```
   __asm("   e_add16i   r5, r3, %lo( machine_check_e500mc )");
   __asm("   mtspr      IVOR1, r5")
   ```
4. When you set the ICEI bit in the L1CSR1 register, the instruction cache will start inserting a parity error into every byte of the instructions fetched from now on. In my case, I had to step a few times until the first instruction with a parity error. You have to consider that the core does instruction prefetching. That means that a few of the instructions on the way are already in the instruction cache by the time you set the ICEI bit. Of course, those instructions do not have parity errors.
5. With the following example code and a debugger (Lauterbach over JTAG), this is what I need to do for the error injection.

   ```
   se_mflr   r0
   e_stwu    r1,-0x10(r1)
   se_stw    r31,0x0C(r1) 
   se_stw    r0,0x14(r1)
   ```

   - Stop your system at a position where the IVOR registers and the cache have been initialized. In my case, this is the first instruction of a function prologue, se_mflr r0.
   - Set a breakpoint at the first instruction in machine_check_e500mc.
   - Set L1CSR1[ICEI] := 1
   - Step a few times. In my case, se_stw r0,0x14(r1) is the first instruction with a parity error.
   - Now you should have hit the breakpoint in machine_check_e500mc.
   - MCSRR0 contains the address of the instruction that was executed when the machine check occurred.
   - I had to set MSR[ME] := 0, otherwise my debugger refused to step any further.
   - Now the first thing you do is to invalidate the cache line with the parity error, as they say in the application note.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work.When we map the handler code to static page ,would it stop it from getting cached? I really couldn't understand what you're doing in step 2 , 3 and 4 .It would be great if you can provide bit more details on these steps  :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've added the explanations to my original answer.

Comment: Thank you again for taking your time out and explaining it ,You said you're doing it on Bare metal(how different doing it on Linux). Also if I inject a MCE for cache ,wouldn't it just stop all kind of access to cache?

Comment: I cannot say how you do this in Linux. Maybe one of their developers can answer it on the mailing list. If you enable the error injection in the cache, you can still execute all the code on uncached pages but none on cached. When you disable the error injection, you need to invalidate all the cache lines with parity errors.